# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*)

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I am trying to run this simple command in Datagrip but this error is showing continuously! Can anyone help me?

" You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*) FROM services_receiver' at line 1 "

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE5Cl.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space after  `COUNT`.

```
select count(*) from ...
            ^----here
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah problem solved!